# Terminate a thread created by <thread> header

Tags: c++

I am making a small program to understand the flow of threads. I am stuck at runtime error. It took me 2 days to figure out that the function which gives runtime error, has a thread running in some other place. Now, I need to close that thread properly so that my main function can terminate properly.

Here is an example of what I made;

```
void main()
{
    int n = fun2();
    cout << n;
}

int fun2()
{
    thread parallel(fun3);
    return 2;
}

void fun3()
{
    while (smth)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The fun3() does file reading part by the way. I read multiple questions related to this issue but none of them were actually helpful, most of them were using HANDLE thingy which I dont understand. If there is any other way to simultaneously execute 2 functions, I would like to know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess, you need thread.join. Take a look at the example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

Comment: Which 2 function do you want to run in parallel? `fun2` and `fun3`?

Comment: @Galik i want to run fun2() and fun3() parallel, and both should terminate when fun2() wants them to. user3159253 i dont want my program to wait for fun3 to complete, i want to run them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a runtime error because `std::thread`  will execute `std::terminate()` if it is not either joined or detached. Your main function finishes without joining the thread that `fun2()` spawned. A simple fix would be just joining the thread in your second function like so:

```
void main()
{
    int n = fun2();
    cout << n;
}

int fun2()
{
    thread parallel(fun3);
    parallel.join() // wait for the thread to finish
    return 2;
}

void fun3()
{
    while (smth)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the work of `fun2()` happens between creating the thread and joining.

Comment: Thats the thing, i don't want it to _wait_ i want to run fun2() and fun3() parallel and both should terminate when fun2() wants.

Comment: @user3762712 Just put the join at the end of `fun2()` and all the code for `fun2()` between creating the thread and the join

Comment: Thanks a lot @Galik i thought my program would still wait but i guess putting it in the end didn't wait for fun3() to complete because i had a remote flag to break the while loop in fun3() thereby completing that function.

Comment: @user3762712 You need to set the `smth` flag before you call the `join` then wait for `fun3()` to end gracefully (also make sure `smth` is atomic or protected by a mutex).

Comment: @user3762712 : fun2() and fun3() already runs in parallel, join doesn't block the thread from the point it is called, the thread is blocked such that it doesn't terminated before the fun3()